# How to fix 'DnsClient.DnsResponseException' error in mongodb driver for Net Core?

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, dns, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to debug my project but sometimes when do a query to mongodb atlas I get the error:

[image]

But sometimes the error does not occur. How do I fix it? 3 days unable to work.

Inner Exception:

Error: Cannot read byte 245, out of range.System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot read byte 245, out of range.   at DnsClient.DnsDatagramReader.ReadByte()   at DnsClient.DnsDatagramReader.ReadLabels()   at DnsClient.DnsDatagramReader.ReadQuestionQueryString()   at DnsClient.DnsRecordFactory.ReadRecordInfo()   at DnsClient.DnsMessageHandler.GetResponseMessage(ArraySegment`1 responseData)   at DnsClient.DnsUdpMessageHandler.Query(IPEndPoint server, DnsRequestMessage request, TimeSpan timeout)   at DnsClient.LookupClient.ResolveQuery(DnsMessageHandler handler, DnsRequestMessage request, Audit continueAudit)

Comment: Paste the error as text in your question, do not use an image.

Comment: I've added now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the error for 3 days, already desperate changed my DNS setting to:

[image: DNS]

Solved! ‍♂️

Comment: Can you elaborate where this settings can be found pls

Comment: @Greatran On your Android phone, goto Settings -> WLAN, find your wifi, click to open setting page, then find place to set IP, change it to use Static instead of DHCP, then you should be able to find places to set DNS

Comment: DnsClient.DnsResponseException: 'Query 23438 => cluster0.7d8pz.mongodb.net IN TXT on 192.168.1.1:53 timed out or is a transient error.'

Still Issue is there after setting DNS. Even after I added my IP to Network Access. But if Changed my WIFI it works.
How can I fix it.